# How to search in array?

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array

```
$data = array(
  array(
    "engine" => "Gecko",
    "browser" => "Firefox 1.0",
    "platform" => "2",
    "version" => "1.7",
    "grade" => "A"
  ), 
  array(
    "engine" => "SHmeko",
    "browser" => "Firefox 1.5",
    "platform" => "1",
    "version" => "1.8",
    "grade" => "B"
  )
);
```

How can I search by elements? in_array doesn't fit, because I need to found all matches,
if I search an 'k', I need it to be found in the elements contents the 'k'.

Comment: From your example no elements contains `k` ???

Comment: Gecko contains k and SHmeko contains k

Comment: Then your question is far from what you want .... update with proper description .. and add your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "") {

        foreach ($data as $sort) {
            foreach ($sort as $key => $val) {
                if (preg_match_all('/' . $_GET['sSearch'] . '/i', $val) != 0) {
                    $new[] = $sort;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isset($new))$data = $new; else $data=0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
$key = array_search('k', $data);
```

Comment: array_search return a key and i need to all array be returned, where the value found

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `array_search`?

```
mixed array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = false ] )
```

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php

Comment: array_search return a key and i need to array be returned

Comment: Then create a function that calls `array_search`, and return the array if the return value of the `array_search` fits what you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
$friends = array( 'Bob', 'Ann', 'Peter' ); // Two persons named 'Bob'
$find = 'Bob';
$key = array_search( $find, $friends ); // Find key of given value
if ($key != NULL || $key !== FALSE) {
    unset($friends[$key]); // remove key from array
}
```

and also you can refer this link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: i need to remove all array if value key don't found, not 1 field

Comment: i have your question but i am not getting which type of output you want-

Answer (score 0):

If you trying search for specific terms/key in this array that you can do this in this manner:
Let’s say if you have to find `A` in array `$data`:

```
$key = array_search(‘A’, $data);
```

After this `$key` will contain the location where it has value ‘A’ against it

In case required value isnot a part of the array it will contain `FALSE`

Hope it solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use:

```
array array_filter ( array $input [, callable $callback = "" ] )
```

with a callback function that uses preg_match() ??

More informations [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)